# Run a json string function

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json string like this:

```
json = "{'run': 'function() { console.log('running...'); }'}"
```

How do I run that function inside of the json string?

Comment: `eval(json.substring(10, json.length-2))();` ? =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to have to use the `eval()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)) function. A lot of people have a lot of feelings about this function. JSON is best for transporting data, not functions (see [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON)). The functions ought to lay in the script on the page.
Also there's a syntax error in your posted code (function is wrapped in single quotes ('), and so is console.log's first parameter).
But...

```
json = "{\"run\":\"function() { console.log('running...'); }\"}"; //Fixed, thanks
obj = JSON.parse(json);
eval(obj.run); //Logs "running..."
```

---

**Update:**

Oh, and I was mistaken. Eval doesn't seem to like anonymous functions. With the revised code, it will parse json into an object with a run property that is a `String`, with value `"function() { console.log('running...'); }"`. But when you `eval(obj.run);`, you will get a SyntaxError declaring an unexpected (. Presumably, this is the ( in function **(**).

So, I can think of two ways of dealing with this:

1. Remove the anonymous function in your actual JSON string (so, make your PHP forget about `function () {`), and eval it. This means it will be called as soon as you `eval` it.
2. What I think you want, is to be able to evaluate it to an anonymous function, that will be called when you want. So, you could write a wrapper function (you would need to follow option 1 for this as well):

   ```
   function returnEval(str) {
       return function () { eval(str); }
   }
   ```

   This would allow you to call it. So:

   ```
   obj = JSON.parse(json);
   obj.run = returnEval(obj.run);
   obj.run(); //Logs "running..."
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the second line gave me in Chrome: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @weng - Fixed it above. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not really intended for that, but [here](http://solutoire.com/2008/06/12/sending-javascript-functions-over-json/) seems to be a good example.

Comment: CouchDB is using this to store map reduce functions in the database. I have to store functions in the database too.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Firefox:

```
var json = "{'run': 'function() { console.log(\\'running...\\'); }'}";
eval('var j = ' + json);
eval('var r = ' + j.run);
r();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works:

```
var JS = { "function" : "alert( new Date().getTime() );" };

new Function ( "", JS["function"] )();
```

for nested functions you also can use something like this:

```
jQuery.each( JS, function( method, value ) {
        new Function ( "a, b", "if ( a == 'function' ) { new Function ( '', b )(); }" )( method, value );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that thread is old but i want to share with you guys. You can make string a json and parse it easily with these functions.

```
function makeString(val){
    return JSON.stringify(val, function (key, value) {if (typeof value == 'function') {return value.toString();}return value;});
}

function parseIt(val){
    return JSON.parse(string, function (key, value) {if (value.toString().search("function")>-1) {eval("var func = " + value);return func;}return value;});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `eval('function()')` you could to create a new function using `new Function(strName)`. The below code was tested using FF, Chrome, IE.

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="test()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test() {

    try {    

        var myJSONObject = {"success" : true, "jsFunc" : "myFunction()"};
        var fnName = myJSONObject.jsFunc;
        var fn = new Function(fnName);
        fn();

      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error:"+err.message);
      }

  }

  function myFunction() {
    console.log('Executing myFunction()');
  }
</script>
```